# Как использовать изображение в проекте

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, изображения, picturebox

Я новичок в c# и не понимаю как использовать изображения для PictureBox, используя относительный путь.

[image: структура проекта]

Изображения лежат в папке images. Нужно его использовать в Form2
Вот что я пробовал, но выдает ошибку FileNotFoundException, хотя я уверен в том, что такой файл есть.

```cs
string finalName = String.Format(@"\images\{0}.jpg", filename.ToLower());
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(finalName);
```

В чем проблема?

UPD: Помогло переместить изображения в Debug, скомбинировав путь выполнения с относительным. Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите, копируется ли этот файл в output folder. Это будет указано в его свойствах (ну, и можно проверить наличие файла в папке bin\Debug.

Comment: Приложение запускается не из папки с исходниками, а из папки bin\Debug, картинки надо положить туда. Чтобы дать окончательный ответ, надо знать версию дотнета.

Comment: Поизучайте класс `Path` - `Path.Combine("images", $"{filename}.jpg")`, никаких `ToLower()` на Windows делать не надо, в винде файловая система регистронезависимая.

Comment: Только через 10 лет пользования Windows узнал, что файловая система в ней регистронезависимая. Я даже протестировал, чтобы убедиться - и правда. Я думал таковыми являются только Unix-системы

Comment: @ЮрычBRO всё наоборот, в UNIX как раз регистрозависимая :)

Answer (score -1):

Папка проекта - это не тоже самое, что папка с программой. Поместите изображение в ресурс и ссылайтесь по его URI или по его имени. Откройте обозреватель решения ПКМ на Properties -> Создать элемент -> Файл ресурсов. И все ресурсы можете писать туда. Файлы, строки, рисунки. Обращаться можно например так:

```
global::Prg.Properties.Resources.excel_import
```

где Prg - имя класса программы

excel_import - имя файла значка (да, без расширения)

Детали смотрите в документации.

Comment: Зачем это, есди автор всего-лишь картинку с диска открыть хочет?

Comment: С относительным путем? Тогда пусть использует диалоговое окно открытия файла. А если заранее знает что именно - ресурс

Comment: Вообще если быть вниметельней, то у него не относительный путь :)

Comment: String.Format(@"\images\{0}.jpg", filename.ToLower()); - Это точно не абсолютный :) Автор - уточни вопрос.

Comment: Относительный относительно чего со слешом в начале?

Comment: Относительно пути запуска программы. Тогда уж - Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, String.Format(@"images\{0}.jpg", filename.ToLower());

Comment: Помогли комментарии Ingvar и Zufir

Comment: @ЮрычBRO вот и получилась угадайка, версию дотнета вы так и не сказали, а StartupPath не везде работает.

Comment: Как я понял, этот ответ бесполезен сам по себе, комментарии полезнее оказались.

Comment: @aepot Мне не особо нужно портируемое решение, я не разработчик, которому нужно подстроить приложение под любые устройства. Это практическое задание в изучении Windows Forms

Comment: @ЮрычBRO при чем тут портируемость? Я просто спросил версию дотнета, потому что в разных версиях можно по-разному каталог запуска приложения определять, только и всего. На основе вашего ответа, можно было бы дать точный, конкретный рабочий ответ с кодом. Но вы предпочли угадывать, ведь Application.StartupPath не во всех версиях одинаково работает, здесь просто повезло.